# React Native adding to an array of states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add an array of to my state of beer. What I am looking to accomplish is based on the users choice of favorite beers it adds those specific values on to the state.

the error I am receiving is that 'undefined is not a function' that points to my function to add the state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Picker, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

class BeerPicker extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          beer: []
      };
  }
  addBeer(newbeer){  <== function throws error
      this.setState((state) => {
          beer: state.addBeer.push(newbeer)
      });
  }
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Picker selectedValue = {this.state.beer} onValueChange = {this.addBeer}>
               <Picker.Item label = "IPA" value = "ipa" />
               <Picker.Item label = "Pilsner" value = "pilsner" />
               <Picker.Item label = "Stout" value = "stout" />
            </Picker>
            <Text style = {styles.text}>{this.state.beer}</Text>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default BeerPicker;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   text: {
      fontSize: 30,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      color: 'red'
   }
})
```

Fairly new to React Native so any input would be much accomplished!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback to `Picker` gives you `itemValue` and `itemIndex`, you'll have to push this in your beer array and do a `bind` in constructor

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        beer: []
    };

    this.addBeer = this.addBeer.bind(this);
}

addBeer(itemValue, itemIndex){ 
    this.setState((state) => {
        beer: [...state.beer, itemValue]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

his problem seems to be context.

try using bind inside your constructor.

`this.addBeer = this.addBeer.bind(this);`

```
constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          beer: []
      };
      this.addBeer = this.addBeer.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: I still receive a type error saying undefined is not an object

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind addBeer inside your constructor and additionally change your addBeer function to this:

```
  addBeer(newbeer) {
      this.setState({
          beer: [...this.state.addBeer, newbeer]
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with adding `this.addBeer = this.addBeer.bind(this)` to your constructor...you should also not make it a habit to use a mutator such as `.push()` in set state.

Try replacing `addBeer()` with:

```
addBeer(newbeer){ 
    this.setState({
        beer: [...this.state.beer, newbeer]
    });
}
```